# Traduction de « pedal power » et « pedal powered »

Tags: traduction, anglais

Comment traduiriez-vous « pedal power » et « pedal powered » dans [cet article](http://www.lowtechmagazine.com/2011/05/pedal-powered-farms-and-factories.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le titre de l'article est « *Pedal powered farms and factories: the forgotten future of the stationary bicycle* ». Avec une *machine agricole* par exemple, on peut imaginer :

> Machine agricole (dont l'[action](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/action) est) [entraînée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entra%C3%AEner)/[entretenue](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entretenir) ([2](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=ent&__index=ent&srchtxt=powered&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0), [3](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=19070130)) par [pédalier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/p%C3%A9dalier).
>  [Énergie
>   (cinétique)](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2081653) [produite](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/produire) par [pédalement/pédalage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/p%C3%A9daler).

La difficulté avec la [*pédale*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/p%C3%A9dale), au-delà de l'acception vulgaire basée sur le jeu de mot, auquel [on a fait](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13969) allusion, c'est l’interférence de [termes](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=frt&__index=frt&srchtxt=p%E9dale&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) où on utilise *la/à pédale* davantage comme dans une voiture; par exemple la [*pédale wah-wah*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18075914), ou des trucs [*à commande au pied (foot actuated)*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=18099154). Si on utilise *animé*, *mu*, ou *propulsé* sans traiter de l'*action* ou du *mécanisme* de la machine, alors on risque d'introduire une ambiguïté et on se demande si la machine se déplace sous l'impulsion du pédalement, ce qui n'est pas le cas de la machine dont le schéma est présenté en début d'article, ou si elle est fixe.<sup>1</sup> C'est pourquoi *entraîné/alimenté/entretenu* semblent plus indiqués ici pour décrire l'*apport* au mouvement ou au mécanisme sans idée de déplacement. Le choix entre *par pédalier* et *par pédalement/pédalage* relève à mon avis de l'explication technique par opposition à l'action génératrice, utilisée ici dans le cas de l'énergie produite ([*cinétique*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cin%C3%A9tique) n'est peut-être pas toujours pertinent). On a des choix.

---

<sub>1. On se rappellera aussi qu'on ne peut dire « [*vélo stationnaire*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8353751) » (aussi [*Franceterme*](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=v%C3%A9lo%20d%27int%C3%A9rieur&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search)), on a donc le *vélo d'intérieur* ou possiblement plus utile, le cas échéant, le *vélo fixe*, moins usuel. Dans le même ordre d'idées, on a peu de succès avec les termes basés sur le préfixe [*cyclo-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cyclo-); on a le *cyclo-rameur* « « *Tricycle d'enfant, dirigé avec les pieds et mû par la force des bras* » (Rob. *Suppl.* 1970). *Cyclo-rameur, jouet sportif* (*Catal. jouets* [Trois-Quartiers], 1936) » (*TLFi*, cyclo-). Le [*support d'entraînement*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8352929) est peu utile à moins qu'on l'utilise à proprement parler dans un montage avec la machine.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Il n'y a pas de traduction  mot à mot proche ; une *machine à pédales* est une machine :

> qui fournit de l'énergie à l'aide de pédaliers,
>
> qui utilise (ou qui fonctionne) avec l'énergie  des pédaliers.

On dira aussi que l'on utilise des vélos ou des bicyclettes pour fournir de l'énergie.

Il ne faut pas sortir le mot *pédale* de son contexte, car c'est une injure homophobe.